# Are for-fun questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have learned a lot reading xkcd and talking about Hal9000 and Solaris over a beer. Granted: that does not make me any expert in AI, by far. But I see some value to it:

- I get to know concepts that I look up afterwards
- I reflect and try to imagine new problems and solutions
- I get another view on news or current (technical) problems I face
- I get some things to procrastinate on

What do you think about questions related to cinema, books and novels, science fiction, etc? What about jokes and funny AI-stuff?

I am not very sharp right now, but maybe something like:

**Was HAL9000 programmed to be an egoistic jerk or he just developed it by itself?**

Or:

**What is your favourite AI-joke?**

([yeah, got it here :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234476))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they're not. "Getting to know you" or fun, minimal-mind questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange. Notice how the Stack Overflow question you linked is locked. If it hadn't been locked for historical significance, it would definitely have been deleted.

Especially during the private beta, we must focus on producing quality content. For fun, try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/artificial-intelligence)!

Answer (score 1):

The first question about HAL9000 I believe is on-topic either on [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), [Sci-fi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) or [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), but not in here, where we require some real-world questions, not related to science fiction.

The second one regarding a joke, the quote from the closure reason from that link says it:

> is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site

this is because opinion-like questions or the one which are asking something from unlimited list of possibilities ['are not a good fit for this type of Q&A site'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/191655). As said by [@RCartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/191655):

> Stack Exchange is well-suited to asking very specific questions that represent real problems you encounter in your day-to-day work. A big part of that process is asking very long-tailed questions; the kind where folks with specific expertise in the subject can propose the best possible answer, which is then voted on so the best possible answers rise to the top.

There was actually Humor site proposal, but it was [closed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24036/61861), because of above reasons.